System of trigonometric eqs: $a\cos(\phi_1) + b\cos(\phi_2) = A$ and $a\sin(\phi_1) + b\sin(\phi_2) = B$
I want to solve the following system of eqs where $ \phi_1 $ and $ \phi_2$ are the unknown variables:
$$a \cdot \cos(\phi_1) + b \cdot \cos(\phi_2) = A $$
$$a \cdot \sin(\phi_1) + b \cdot \sin(\phi_2) = B $$
What I have done so far: I found $\cos (\phi_1 - \phi_2) = x$  with
$$ x = \frac{A^2 + B^2 - a^2 - b^2}{2 a b} $$
then I go back into my system and I replace everywhere $ \phi_1 = \phi_2 + \arccos(x) $ and I use the fact that
$$ \cos(\arccos(x)) = x$$
$$ \sin(\arccos(x)) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$$
Finally, I found that:
$$\cos(\phi_2) = \frac{u \cdot A + v \cdot B}{u^2 + v^2}$$
$$\sin(\phi_2) = \frac{u \cdot B - v \cdot A}{u^2 + v^2}$$
where $u$ and $v$ are:
$$ u = a \cdot x + b$$
$$ v = a \cdot \sqrt{1 - x^2}$$
However when I tested this on python, the results are completely off.
EDIT 1:
I think the problem is related to the following relation:
$ \phi_1 = \phi_2 + arccos(x) $
This is not always correct, sometimes can be:
$ \phi_1 = \phi_2 - arccos(x) $
Based on the coefficients a, b, A and B, how can I know which relation holds? Important note:
$ a > 0 $ and $ b > 0$

Have you tried defining x=cos(phi_1) and y=cos(phi_2)? You end up with a fourth degree polynomial to solve in x.

Try this:
$$a\cos\phi_1-A=-b\cos\phi_2$$
$$a\sin\phi_1-B=-b\sin\phi_2$$
Square and add both sides to get:
$$(a\cos\phi_1-A)^2+(a\sin\phi_1-B)^2=b^2$$
$$a^2\cos^2\phi_1+A^2-2aA\cos\phi_1+a^2\sin^2\phi_1+B^2-2aB\sin\phi_1=b^2$$
$$A\cos\phi_1+B\sin\phi_1=\frac{a^2-b^2+A^2+B^2}{2a}=c$$
$$\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\cos\phi_1+\frac B{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\sin\phi_1=\frac c{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$
$$\cos(\phi_1-\theta)=\cos k_1$$
$$\phi_1=\theta+k_1$$
where I have taken:
$$\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right)$$
and
$$k_1=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac c{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right)$$
Similarly, we can start it in the other way to find:
$$a\cos\phi_1=A-b\cos\phi_2$$
$$a\sin\phi_1=B-b\sin\phi_2$$
Following the similar previous steps:
$$a^2=A^2+B^2+b^2-2bA\cos\phi_2-2bB\sin\phi_2$$
$$A\cos\phi_2+B\sin\phi_2=\frac{b^2-a^2+A^2+B^2}{2b}=d$$
$$\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\cos\phi_2+\frac B{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\sin\phi_2=\frac d{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$
$$\cos(\phi_2-\theta)=\cos k_2$$
$$\phi_2=\theta+k_2$$
where I have taken:
$$k_2=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac d{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right)$$
And finally the result is:
$$
\phi_1=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right)+\cos^{-1}\left(\frac {a^2-b^2+A^2+B^2}{2a\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right)
$$
$$
\phi_2=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right)+\cos^{-1}\left(\frac {b^2-a^2+A^2+B^2}{2b\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right)
$$

Hint.
This problem is equivalent to
$$
a z_1 + b z_2 = C_0,\ \ |z_1|=|z_2| = 1, \{a, b\}\in \mathbb{R}
$$
so a geometrical construction to its solution follows, supposing that $|C_0|\le |a|+|b| $
In blue $a z_1$, in blue dashed $(|a|+|b|)z_2$ in red $C_0$ and in green the two circles of radius $|b|$, solutions to the problem. Note that the center of the solution circles can be obtained as the intersection of circles $|z-C_0| = |b|$ and $|z|= |a|$.


I prefer to show the geometry not the algebra.

I greatly appreciate your interest in my response. Thank you.
